# bad number of element in dynamic array with for each loop

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop

I don't understand why for each loop in vba doesn't return the good number of element when i use dynamic array.

For exemple, my array size is 4, and i have 5 iteration in for each loop ...

```
Public Sub test()

Dim t_direction() As String
Dim t_nextDirection() As String
Dim myDirection As Variant
Dim test As Integer
Var = 0

ReDim t_direction(4)

t_direction(0) = "N"
t_direction(1) = "S"
t_direction(2) = "E"
t_direction(3) = "W"

t_nextDirection = randomizeArray(t_direction)

For Each myDirection In t_nextDirection
    Var = Var + 1
Next myDirection

MsgBox (UBound(t_nextDirection))
MsgBox (Var)

End Sub

Public Function randomizeArray(ByVal t_array As Variant) As String()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim tmp As String
Dim numItems As Integer

numItems = UBound(t_array) - 1

    ' Randomize the array.
    For i = 0 To numItems
        ' Pick a random entry.
        j = Rand(0, numItems)

        ' Swap the numbers.
        tmp = t_array(i)
        t_array(i) = t_array(j)
        t_array(j) = tmp
    Next i
    'MsgBox (UBound(t_array))
    randomizeArray = t_array

End Function

Public Function Rand(ByVal Low As Long, _
                     ByVal High As Long) As Integer
  Rand = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd) + Low
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment you are creating a 5 element array with
`ReDim t_direction(4)`
as the first element occurs as   `t_direction(0)`

You should either

- create a 4 element array `ReDim t_direction(3)`  (ie 0 to 3) and then use `numItems` consistent with that, or
- create a 4 element array `ReDim t_direction` with a base of 1  (ie 1 to 4) and then use `numItems` consistent with that (ie `numItems = UBound(t_array)`). The `Option Base 1` below forces the first element to be 1 (which is then ensured anyow by using `ReDim t_direction(1 To 4)`

The code below uses the later approach. It returns 4 and 4 rather than your current 4 and 5

```
Option Base 1
Public Sub test()

Dim t_direction() As String
Dim t_nextDirection() As String
Dim myDirection As Variant
Dim test As Integer
Var = 0

ReDim t_direction(1 To 4)

t_direction(1) = "N"
t_direction(2) = "S"
t_direction(3) = "E"
t_direction(4) = "W"

t_nextDirection = randomizeArray(t_direction)

For Each myDirection In t_nextDirection
    Var = Var + 1
Next myDirection

MsgBox (UBound(t_nextDirection))
MsgBox (Var)

End Sub

Public Function randomizeArray(ByVal t_array As Variant) As String()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim tmp As String
Dim numItems As Integer

numItems = UBound(t_array)

    ' Randomize the array.
    For i = 1 To numItems
        ' Pick a random entry.
        j = Rand(1, numItems)

        ' Swap the numbers.
        tmp = t_array(i)
        t_array(i) = t_array(j)
        t_array(j) = tmp
    Next i
    'MsgBox (UBound(t_array))
    randomizeArray = t_array

End Function

Public Function Rand(ByVal Low As Long, _
                     ByVal High As Long) As Integer
  Rand = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd) + Low
End Function
```

Comment: nice shot, as always :) and congrats for the 5000+, you've been there very quickly

Answer (score 2):

`ReDim t_direction(4)` actually declares `t_direction` as `0 To 4`

Its better to be explicit:

```
ReDim t_direction(0 To 3)
```

In the absence of a specified lower bound (using the `To` clause), then the default lower bound is used.
This default can be set to `0` or `1` by using `Option Base {0|1}` at module level.
In the absence of `Option Base` then the default default is `0`

Notes:

In VBA you are not limited to `0` or `1` as the lower bound, you can use any value you want.

To iterate over an array use

```
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
```

To calculate the number of items in an array use

```
numItems = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
```

This way you are not making any assumptions on what the lower bound is

Comment: Making this single change doesn't address the issue. It simply moves the issue from 4/5 to 3/4

Comment: @Brettdj The root of the issue is bad assumptions on the operation of `Redim` and undersatnding of lower bounds.  This answer is attempting to address the root problem, rather than simply debugging his code

Comment: your original answer only went part way on the *root issue* as it didn't address the inconsistency on the bounding of `numItems`.